# How do I implement this?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

[image]

I want to implement that cell that says "Show Details". I was thinking maybe to make a custom tableview cell specifically for that cell. But if there is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return a well configured cell for the last cell number, in the the first section.  This looks like a normal cell, with a simple label.

Comment: a well configured cell. I don't understand.

Comment: I tried centering the cell like this cell.textLabel.center = @"Text" but it doesn't work.

Comment: the `center` property is related to the label **position**. use `cell.textLabel.textAlignement = UITextAlignmentCenter;` instead ;) in combination of course `cell.textLabel.text = @"Show details";`

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple. Just add UIButton custom type on second row of 1st section and when you tap on it just show another cells. and reload tableview.

```
[cell addSubView:btnShowDetails];
```